# is it possible to open a popup with javascript and run once

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Is it possible (and how?) to make it only run, once, that the function does not continue to be executed once closed

```
;(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5)
        $("#xpopup").show("slow");else $("xpopup").hide("slow");

});

})(jQuery);

function closePopup(){
    jQuery('#xpopup').hide('slow');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="xpopup" style="display: none;">
    <a style="position:absolute;top:14px;right:10px;color:#999;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return closePopup();">
        <img src="close.png" width="18" height="18"/>
    </a>
    popup content
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'd do this by adding the `scroll` listener using [jQuery's `.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0):

After displaying the popup, remove the scroll handler with [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
if($(document).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() / 5) {
    $("#xpopup").show("slow");
    $(window).off('scroll');
}
```

Note that this will remove *all* scroll handlers from the window. If you only have one, that's not a problem. If you have more, store a reference to this scroll handler and pass it to `.off()`:

```
$(window).off('scroll', myScrollPopupHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use singleton

```
function singleton(){
    let instance;

  let createInstance = function(){
    return 'I exist';  //replace with actual object (e.g. your instance that would cause the alert)

  }

  return {
    createAlert : function(){
        if(!instance){
        instance = createInstance();
        alert(instance);
      }
    }
  }
}();

singleton.createAlert(); //this would go into your desired event
```

The reason why this might be a good way to do it is that you would likely replace `alert` with some other action. In that case all you need to do is to replace instance with whatever object that may cause the invokation (e.g. bootstrap alert).